# Can "prefer" be used in this case?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

Imagine the following conversation.

> **A:** Oh, there is Bugs Bunny on television.
>   **B:** Who is Bugs Bunny? Is it your new boyfriend?
>   **A:** I don't have a new boyfriend; I prefer my *old* boyfriend.

B just wants to know of whom A is speaking; maybe Bugs Bunny is the nick used for a celebrity or for a person A knows, not to mean that [Bugs Bunny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugs_Bunny).

Is *prefer* correct, in this case? Looking at the definition given from the dictionary, I read the following.

> to like one thing or person better than another; to choose one thing rather than something else because you like it better

In this case, there isn't a second person for which the comparison can be done. I would think that "I like my *old* boyfriend." is a better phrase.
Is it really so, or is there any reason to use *prefer* in this context?

Should I understand "I prefer my *old* boyfriend." as "I prefer still having my *old* boyfriend than not having a boyfriend."? Is *prefer* really used with that meaning?

Comment: I think it's sort of silly to apply such rigorous logic to jocular conversation. Your question posits the existence of X; your friend picks up the joke and runs with it.

Comment: Except that my friend didn't pick up the joke, and didn't run with it. It's the third time I make a similar joke, and she is serious when she says "I don't have a new boyfriend." and the next sentences.

Comment: Well, she may mistake the meaning of *prefer*; but she may mean "I prefer my old, real boyfriend to any imaginary alternative." Perhaps her sense of humor is subtler than you think. :)

Comment: It could be, but I am not asking what she meant. `:)`

Comment: When I read the sentence, I assumed @StoneyB's interpretation. "I would rather have my old boyfriend than [any other that might have been implied from the conversation]".

Comment: @WendiKidd The conversation didn't imply any other boyfriend; the conversation was about an imaginary person from a song. Imagine the topic was Bugs Bunny, and somebody says "I prefer my _old_ boyfriend."

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Let me attempt to paraphrase how I thought you said the conversation went: **Her:** "Bugs Bunny is so awesome! Yay Bugs Bunny." **You:** "What, is Bugs Bunny your new boyfriend?" **Her:** "Of course not, I don't have a new boyfriend. I prefer my old boyfriend." So, where am I misunderstanding this? Maybe then I can help. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd That sounds like saying "I don't have a new car; I prefer my old car." The comparison is between not having a car and having the old car. Isn't _prefer_ used as in "I prefer talking to Michelle than Laura"? Otherwise, I would expect the sentence to be "I like my old car better."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We often use language as though one thing is really something else.  In this example, the imaginary person may not *literally* exist, but for the sake of the sentence they're *pretending* they do.

This is really no different from saying something like this while I'm searching for my lost car keys:

> Where did you go!?  Stupid keys.

The keys aren't actually stupid; they aren't animate, so they couldn't have gone anywhere; and they wouldn't normally be addressed with the second-person pronoun "you".  But since I'm *personifying* the keys, I'm acting *as though* they're a real person I can talk to.

We use this kind of metaphor in speech all the time, and it's more general than just personification.  If we speak as though A is B, the speech isn't necessarily *wrong*--it just shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: Good answer - particularly the final sentence. As I recall, this isn't the first time OP has queried the validity of some usage on the grounds of *logic*, despite clear evidence that idiomatically it is something that people do actually say. Note that you can also say *"I lost my stupid key"* - which could to the literal-minded imply said key is being personified (and is thus capable of being characterised as "intellectually challenged").

Comment: It's not a matter of logic. In Italian, if a woman would tell me "I don't have a new boyfriend; I prefer my _old_ boyfriend." I would understand it as "I prefer my _old_ boyfriend to all the men who are around me and who want to be my new boyfriend." Querying the validity of a phrase is something learners often do, as they don't know if a phrase is idiomatic or contains a typo, nor do they know if the phrase can be generalized.

Comment: @snailboat Can I say "I don't have any car; I prefer my old car."?